# Mr Cohen never came down the stairs

Tags: bioshock

I have completed Cohen's masterpiece yet he never came down the stairs. The music and cheers played but no Cohen. *I already knew about the key and the end-game upgrade. I also went back to the area where the fenced-off room was and the barriers are there but they only block a solid wall. I am not receiving any active goals at this point. Help.